# Django: can't access OneToOneField after rendering TemplateView Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django and don't understand what really is causing this:

I have a Model Company which has an OneToOneField, creator.

```
# models.py
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Company'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'
    creator = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have a TemplateView class to handle get and post requests for creating a Company model:

```
# views.py
class create_company(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        form = CompanyCreateForm()    
        title = "Some form"    
        return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form, "title": title})

    def post(self, request):
        form = CompanyCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comp = form.save(commit=False)
            comp.creator = request.user      
            comp.save()
            return redirect('index')
```

The form is showing correctly also storing when I submit, the problem I am facing is with base.html where I show {% user.company %}; the form template extends it like:

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<br>
</div>
<br>
{% endblock %}
```

and in base.html I access

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% user.company %}
{% endif %}
```

But user.company is not showing even it is set; it shows only when I redirect to index but not when I render the form.

Can someone help me understand what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% request.user.company %}
{% endif %}
```

you are not sending any context to the `base.html`, thus only `user` wont work.

Comment: Just tried but nothing is changing; still not working

Comment: yes, because you cant put that in base.html, you need to put it here, make a block in base.html and put this code within that block in form.html

Comment: Actually that is in the navbar, and is showing if the user is authenticated.. :/

Comment: not a problem, just put a block at that place and call that block from form.html

Comment: Created another base.html just for the form and include that nav part in form.html; it is working but pretty sure is not the proper way I should do that since base.html and base_form.html are the same except for this nav dropdown block which is moved to form.html. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This was the error when I simulated your code.

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/user/django/drf_tutorial/snippets/templates/base.html, error at line 2
Invalid block tag on line 2: 'user.company', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
1   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
2       {% user.company %}
3   {% endif %}
4   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

It gives hint that the code to show company should be variable `{{ }}` instead of tag `{% %}`. So the base.html template should be as below.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.company }}
{% endif %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```